# Magento Admin Error

Tags: admin, error, registry

Starting yesterday, whenever I try to go to admin I get the following error:

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Mage registry key "_singleton/all/update" already exists

Any idea why?

Just to clarify: this error comes up instead of the Magento admin login page, I can't login.

Comment: Did you try to clear your cache via commandline?

Comment: I'm sure a quick clear cache will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the folder `{magento_rootdir}/var/cache` folder manually since you can't refresh cache from Admin panel.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was worried for the past 24 hours and I didn't realize it was as simple as deleting a single folder!

Comment: Any idea what was causing this error?

Comment: Normally I get these errors after removing/installing an extension. However it can happen anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793897/mage-registry-key-singleton-core-resource-already-exists-in-magento

Since your admin is not working, try ssh into your server and clear your cache.

Magento keeps its cache in /var/cache located inside the Magento installation directory.

> rm -fr /path-to-magento/var/cache